# How Can I Return `nil` for HTTPURLResponse?

Tags: nshttpurlresponse

I have the following method which I used for retrieving a cookie from response headers:

```swift
internal static func cookie(from response: HTTPURLResponse) -> HTTPCookie? {
    guard let url = response.url else { return nil }
    guard let headerFields = response.allHeaderFields as? HTTPHeaders else { return nil }
    let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: url)
    for cookie in cookies {
        if cookie.name == "connect.sid" { return cookie }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I am creating unit tests to verify that my code returns `nil` for appropriate scenarios. However, the only part of the above method that I cannot seem to test effectively is:

```swift
guard let url = response.url else { return nil }
```

In my test, I create a response to pass into the above method:

```swift
guard let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: url, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: responseHeaders) else { fatalError("Invalid response") }
```

Since the initializer for `HTTPURLResponse` requires a non-optional `URL`, I can't seem to figure out how to test the response with a `nil` value for its `url` property.

Is there a way for me to test this with a `nil` `url`?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `HTTPURLResponse()` initializer instead of passing parameters, I was able to have a `nil` value for the response's `url` property.